# Populate the same item from various pages without direct conenction between them. Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I need to Scrape Landing page and some pages that originate from this Landing page.  And save all data into the same item.  The originated pages **do not connect** between themselfs. What is the available way to do so? Is there any way that i can get(load) yielded item and add some info to it? 
What I can think of is initiating a dict in spider itself but that seems very bad idea.
Here is a schema for better understanding. Sorry for my painting skills))
[image]

Say if i create item on page 1 (google) and send it as meta to all other links. Will Yielding the item from all 4 links come together and generate full item with info from 5 urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I came up with two solutions.

**Solution #1.** As posted in original post send item to all the links via meta and add dictionary value to the same item field. Say `item['links_info']={}`. So every page will have its own key and data assigned to this item dict.

**Solution #2.** Save all links that need to be visited into a list. Follow 1 url from this list at a time and pass the rest via meta. Also pass item along.

The first one looks easier to implement though.